# tensorflow running one batch at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am loading in my data via a shuffle_batch input pipeline.  However, when I go to do training, I would like to train for a bit, then python some things, then continue training.  However, I'm not sure how to get control of the thing back from the `shuffle_batch` reader and the filename queue.  It just keeps reading and reading...

**EDIT::** I realize that this is the "old way" to import data.  However, I do not immediately see a way to remedy this with the "new way" https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/data/FixedLengthRecordDataset

How do I feed just 50 cifar records through my training pipeline and then recover control in my jupyter notebook?

Comment: Whilest you can limit the length of the input/dataset. I think what you want to do is related to how you run the training and tell it to only run for so many or a single step. Your code would help to provide more tailored advice.

Comment: I am using a minorly altered version of the cifar10 tensorflow tutorial.  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/ - the actual ltraining happens when it is [executing the train_op](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/0785f0c037806584b000fe7b2b2ae8888980f3ed/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L115). You should be able to put your logic there. e.g.:

```
while not mon_sess.should_stop():
  mon_sess.run(train_op)
  if mon_sess.run(global_step) % 10 == 0:
    # do something special
```

Otherwise it also supports a [max_steps](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/0785f0c037806584b000fe7b2b2ae8888980f3ed/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py#L51) parameter which would probably be similar to you trying to limit the input. But wouldn't be so useful if you then want to continue training.

Comment: I got ahead of myself on accepting this.  :)  It has helped me narrow down the problem, however.  See the update with a section of code that is more stackoverflow-sized.

Comment: Not seeing any update. But it will be difficult to answer future questions in advance ;-)

Comment: The update is visible now but it seems to be a quite different question now. I suspect it's because the queue runners have not been started.

Comment: Good point about the different question.  I will edit this back, and open a new question.  Give me a bit and I will investigate the queue runner clue and attempt to answer it myself.